# Get array of custom NSObjects in ObjectiveC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiview, appdelegate

I have a `SPObject` class, which is a custom `NSObject`. In the `viewDidLoad` method of the `ViewController`, I am creating an instance of `SPObject`. There is also a button which, on clicked, creates a new `SPObject`.

When my app goes to the background, I want to save these `SPObject`s in the database. So, in the `applicationDidEnterBackground` method, I am getting the instance of the main ViewController using

`ViewController * vc = (ViewController *)self.viewController;`

I want to know how I can get a list of the current `SPObject`s in the next line of the above line.

If what I wanted was a list of UIViews, I could have just done,

```
for(UIView * subView in vc.view.subviews)
```

which would have returned a good list.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are they stored in a property or array somewhere in that view controller?

Comment: For stuff like this you may want to use Core Data.

Comment: Do you want these objects to survive at every app execution?

Comment: Yes, that's why I need to store them in a database. That's why I need a list of the objects when the app enters background.

Answer (score 1):

Have an array property of your objects:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *objects;
```

When you create new object add it to this array:

```
[self.objects addObject:newSPobject];
```

When entering background get this array:

```
NSMutableArray *objects = vc.objects;
```

Now you can do with this array whatever you like

Comment: Is there an advantage to using a property for this, instead of just an instance variable? It seems to me that using a property is more complicated if the data isn't needed outside the object.

Comment: you still want to use property even if you don't access it outside of the class because it is easier to retain the object

Comment: The values in the SPObject instance keep changing so I need to get a list of the objects only at the end when going to the background.

Comment: Hrm. I don't have the advantage of coding in ObjC without ARC; is this still the case when ARC (which seems to be the norm now) is in use?

Comment: @CharlesD'Monte isn't it easier to maintain this list as you go, rather than try to put it together later?

Comment: The values in the SPObject instance keep changing so I need to get a list of the objects only at the end when going to the background. So, if I change the value in the SPObject after adding it to the array, the object in the array will have the same old values. So, there is no use of having outdated objects.

Comment: @CharlesD'Monte and how you keep references to each newly created object without having an array? what if i press the button a hundred times?

Comment: @CharlesD'Monte if you just change of value in the object the value in the array should also change cause array keeps references to objects

Comment: @mah yes, it's still applicable even under ARC. check this http://ironwolf.dangerousgames.com/blog/archives/913

Comment: @AndreyChernukha Arrays dont update the values. They just have the objects with the old values.

Comment: @CharlesD'Monte i don't understand how you keep references. Where all the objects you've created are stored?

Comment: @mah - The OP needs the data outside the object.  That was his whole question.

Comment: To the upvoter, don't upvote if you don't know that the answer won't work.

Comment: @CharlesD'Monte - You fail to understand how an NSArray works.  It contains only pointers to the objects, not copies of the objects.  If you modify one of the objects, the changes will be visible via the array.

Comment: @AndreyChernukha they are not stored anywhere. I just want to get them dynamically. Please read my question properly. I want the SPObjects through a for loop. I dont need to store them anywhere. So when I go to the background, the objects with the updated values are available in the for loop. Please dont argue if you cant give what I need. The array solution WON'T WORK. Pls try out your solution to make sure it works.

Comment: UIView * a = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 0, 0)];
    NSArray * array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:a];
    [a setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    NSLog(@"%f",a.frame.origin.x);Try this code.

Comment: @CharlesD'Monte buddy, you ain't right, ask anyone if you don't believe me. You MUST have an array. In your question you give an example for(UIView * subView in vc.view.subviews) and subviews is AN ARRAY. How are you going to obtain the values if you don't store it? Show all your code